# Update DataSet in VB.Net As Table is Changed in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

My Scenario is that i have fetch data from one SQL Server table into vb.net DataTable.

Now if any record is changed or New Record is saved into SQL Server Table i want to fetch or update only that record into my data table. is it possible.

This is because my SQL Table has more than 1 million records and fetching all records every time is almost impossible.

Actually i am going to built a Bar Chart from sale invoice table and it will refresh data after every 1 min or fix interval of time.

Comment: You could select the record count, if it differs from Datatable.Count, select only the newest record(s).

Comment: You have 1 million rows in your `DataTable`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter this will only return new records, won't recognize modified ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a timestamp field to your table. Set it to the current time on insert and update, then query for all records that have a timestamp greater that the greatest timestamp from the last query.

Comment: Thank You This is a good trick and help me to solve my prblem

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlDependency for data change events. This will ensure whatever changes to a specific table in the database occurs, will automatically trigger an event to reflect the changes in your program.

1. enable broker in your databasest

   ALTER DATABASE [yourdbName] SET ENABLE_BROKER
2. A dependency is created between the application and the database via a SqlCommand. Before that can be established, the SqlDependency must be started for this session.

   SqlDependency.Start(m_ConnectionString);
3. As stated before, the dependency is created based on a SqlCommand.

   SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);

   There are some restrictions, of course, as to what can be included in this command. The command must use two part names and not use *. It also must obviously not be an UPDATE or INSERT statement.

The following won't work:

```
SELECT * FROM Message
```

This will work:

```
SELECT ID, Message FROM dbo.Message
```

4. If the query is not correct, an event will immediately be sent with:

   SqlNotificationEventArgs.Info = Query

   SqlNotificationEventArgs.Source = Statement

   SqlNotificationEventArgs.Type = Subscribe

For detail example and demo application see [Using SqlDependency for data change events](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events)